# How to call external method with struct parameter that contains union

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

The C++ code is:

```
DLL_API DWORD WINAPI ExecuteCommand( LPCSTR, CONST COMMAND, CONST DWORD, LPREPLY);

typedef struct
{
    REPLY_TYPE      replyType;

    union
    {
        POSITIVE_REPLY  positiveReply;
        NEGATIVE_REPLY  negativeReply;
    }
    message;

}
REPLY;
```

And my C# code is:

```
public struct Reply
{
    public ReplyType ReplyType;

    public PositiveReply PositiveReply;
    public NegativeReply NegativeReply;
}

[DllImport(@"my.dll")]
public static extern int ExecuteCommand(string port, Command command, int timeout, ref Reply reply);
```

How can I properly transfer union to C# code? When I call ExecuteCommand I receive reply which should contain either Positive or Negative Reply (such does C++ method).

Comment: Have a look at [FieldOffsetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: From a c# perspective you are passing a structure that contains a REPLY_TYPE.  All c# care about is the size of the object.  In c language a union is a definition that can contain multiple items, but it is actually just a single item stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replicate C union in C#. You should do something like this (change type names and constants according to your real code):

`public struct Reply
        {
            public int rt;
            public object o;
            public int? pr { get { return rt == 1 ? (int?)o : null; } }
            public int? nr { get { return rt == 0 ? (int?)o : null; } }
        }`